# simple application of Bezout's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f(x),g(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ be two irreducible homogeneous polynomials of degree $n,m$ respectively. Does Bezout's Theorem say that the system of equations $f(x)=0, g(x)=0$ has precisely $m \cdot n$ solutions?

Now let $y(y_1,\cdots,y_n)$ be a new set of indeterminates. Then $f(x+y),g(x+y)$ are still homogeneous of degree $m,n$ respectively, albeit they lie in the rings $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\cdots,x_n,y_1,\cdots,y_n]$. Does Bezout's Theorem say that the system of equations $f(x+y)=0, g(x+y)=0$ has still $m \cdot n$ solutions?

Comment: No. Intuitively, the locus $f(x) = g(x) = 0$ has dimension $n - 2$, so it will be infinite if $n \ge 3$. For example, take $f = x_1, g = x_2$.

Comment: Generically, $f(x) = 0$ defines you a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. Intersection of two hypersurfaces generically gives you something of codimension 2, which would be an infinite set when $n-1 - 2 > 0$, i.e. when $n > 3$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit:  As noted by Sanchez, condition (3) had to be corrected from its original formulation.

No, what is true is that if you take $n$ polynomials of degrees $d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n$, in $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ then they have exactly $d_1 d_2 \cdots d_n$ common solutions provided:

(1) you count your solutions over an algebraically closed field (no problem here, since you're working over $k = \mathbb{C}$);

(2) you count the number of solutions in projective space (i.e. you have to homogenize your system of equations and then only count nonzero solutions up to rescaling);

(3) the $n$ polynomials must intersect in only a finite number of points (it is necessary, but not sufficient, that the $n$ polynomials are pairwise relatively prime); this condition will hold for a *generic* choice of $n$ polynomials in $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$;

(4) you count each solution with an appropriate *intersection multiplicity*.

In addition to these requirements, Bezout's theorem is only applicable when the number of equations is the same as the number of variables; intuitively, you are starting in an $n$-dimensional space $\mathbb{C}^n$ -- actually $\mathbb{CP}^n$ by (2) -- and each of the $n$ equations cuts down the common solution space by $1$ dimension, resulting in a $0$ dimension intersection (i.e. a finite set of points).  Condition (3) is to insure that you indeed get a $0$ dimensional intersection, while conditions (1) and (4) make sure that you count every solution, the intersection multiplicities coming in because you must count some solutions repeatedly as necessitated by the relevant algebra in the proof.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer. But why is my assertion false? It seems that (1) and (3) are true in my example, since i assume that $f \neq g$ (even though i did not mention that) and since they are irreducible, then they must be relatively prime. Also, they are already homogeneous so (2) is valid as well.

Comment: @Manos What about (4)?

Comment: You have two equations in an $n-1$ dimensional space, so you better take $n=3$.  And count solutions by (2) [not counting all solutions literally], and include multiplicities by (4).

Comment: @mbrown: (4) does not seem a problem. I think the real problem is what Michael added in his answer and Qiaochu and Sanchez commented on, that the number of equations has to be equal to the number of unknowns.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce: Got it.

Comment: @Manos (4) will be a problem, because if $f$ intersects $g$ at some point with multiplicity greater than 1, you won't end up with m*n distinct solutions.  Bezout's theorem only counts solutions up to multiplicity.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce, Actually, (3) is not quite right, since with fixed $f_1$, $f_2$, one can take $f_3 = f_1 + cf_2$ for some polynomial $c$ which can be made to be coprime with $f_1,f_2$, while does not cut down the dimension. The point is really the $n$ hypersurfaces give a complete intersection, and I'm not sure if this condition can be made explicit on polynomials.

Comment: @Sanchez: Right, thanks!  For two polynomials, it can be expressed as a gcd condition, but otherwise the gcd condition is only necessary, not sufficient.  Will edit accordingly.